# C++ ambiguous call to overloaded function with unsigned int

Tags: c++, integer-promotion

This seems inconsistent. I have 3 functions `f` overloaded for signed types `short`, `int` and `long long`. If you pass an `unsigned short` then it gets promoted to the next biggest signed type `int`. However if you pass `unsigned int` then it doesn't get promoted to signed `long long` which is what I would expect, rather compiler complains about ambiguous call to overloaded function.

```
void f(short x) { std::printf("f(short)\n"); }
void f(int x) { std::printf("f(int)\n"); }
void f(long long x) { std::printf("f(long long)\n"); }

int main()
{
    f((unsigned short)0); // Fine: calls f(int)
    // f((unsigned int)0); // Ambiguous: could be f(short), f(int) or f(long long) 
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect that and what is your question? Why it is like this? or how to make it less ambiguous ?

Comment: Yes what is the rationale?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *is* inconsistent, yes, but it is The Way The Language Is, and you have to cope, e.g. if you want `f((unsigned int)0)` to call the `long long` overload, then provide a wrapper,

```
inline void f(unsigned int x) { f((long long)x); }
```

The designers of C++ would have ideally liked to make both of your cases *fail* overload resolution.  But there was this legacy thing (dating all the way back to "K&R" C), called "default argument promotion", that, essentially, says the compiler will implicitly convert all integer types narrower than `int` to `int` if necessary to match a function signature, and all floating point types narrower than `double` to `double` ditto.

So it's the `f((unsigned short)0)` case that is the odd man out, really.

Answer (score 4):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Integral promotion does **not** get you from `unsigned int` to `long long`.

Integral promotion **does** get you from `unsigned short` to `int`.

Integral conversion from `unsigned int` is considered equally good for your overloads.

Promotion *ends* at `int` and/or `unsigned int` unless your source type is an `enum` that requires a larger integral type to fit it.

Promotion is preferred to conversion, so your first case is unambiguous.  In the second case, there is no promotion path, so your code is ambiguous.